# Java EE Adding Data after generate Database

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, orm, wildfly

I have troubles to add some data to my Mysql Data base :
i work with redhat jboss and wildfly 9.x server
i generated my entities , so it seems like my server work fine,
but when i started to add some data in my client project ,
it keep show me an error that is No EJB receiver available for handling .
this is my Service :

```
String jndiName = "examen2018-ear/examen2018-ejb/ServiceEmployee!tn.esprit.examen2018.services.EmployeeServiceRemote";
    Context context = new InitialContext();


    EmployeeServiceRemote employeeServiceRemote = (EmployeeServiceRemote) context.lookup(jndiName);

    Employee emp1 = new Employee();
    emp1.setFirstName("Mohamed");
    emp1.setLastName("Boujouma");
    emp1.setPassword("emp");
    emp1.setEmployeeType(EmployeeType.EMP);
    employeeServiceRemote.ajouterEmployee(emp1);
```

My Service Link generated from wildfly:

```
    java:jboss/exported/examen2018-ear/examen2018-ejb/ServiceEmployee!tn.esprit.examen2018.services.EmployeeServiceRemote
```

My implimentation for ajouterEmployee :

```
@Override
public void ajouterEmployee(Employee employe) {

    em.persist(employe);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

is more heplfull if you add your server log to find out which is the actual error, but in general i recomend you to stop usign like that the connection to the database, it is easier to you leave that to a framework . I recomend Hibernate : 
[Hibernate page](http://hibernate.org/orm/)
I should check this steps to connect to a db:

1. Check if you create de Data source in the wildfly server.
2. Use a framework to handle the connection : recommend Hibernate. Is realy easy
3. Check if the Data Source name is correct in your application.

The "Client" that you mention should be in the EJB context, so you must use EJB anotations, as you mention that the error : no EJB Reciver. Ones again use correctly EJB'S for this process. I recommend this link to understand a little bit more of EBJ'S

[Undestand EJB ORACLE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/ejb30/understanding.html)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use remote ejb to call from client application to server or calling this bean inside your sever? Given you are using remote I will assume the first option. The first thing you should do is look at the remote ejb example from the quickstarts to see how you configure the client connection and lookup a bean, then once you understand that, move on to trying to then call your own code